# What can be the cause that STORE_HTML_OK is not set in PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK on exchange 2010 on SBS 2011?

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

Hi we recently installed an SBS 2011 server for one of our clients and we had some problems using software that creates messages using mapi on exchange 2010. After investigation we found out that the root cause of this problem is that STORE_HTML_OK is not set in the PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK.

The weird thing is we (the firm, one of my collegues) did the installation of the sbs 2011 server with exchange 2010 for the client where STORE_HTML_OK is not set, during my investigation of the problem we installed another sbs 2011 server for testing purposes and there STORE_HTML_OK is set whereas it wasn't in the previous installation.

I would like to know what could cause the STORE_HTML flag not to be set in PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK on exchange 2010, i also would like to know if we can still change this somehow by changing settings in exchange management console or shell ?

We would like our futurue sbs 2011 servers always to have the STORE_HTML to be set in the PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK and like to know what could have caused it not to be set.

Thanks in advance
Willems Davy

EDIT:
Our new sbs 2011 installation has the same problem, i was always testing the code from a client pc where outlook was installed and when outlook is install the mapi version of outlook is used so when running the code from a client with outlook 2007 or even outlook 2003 installed the issue is not there, When installing the mapi runtime (messaging api and datacolaboration objects ...) on SBS2011 the problem is the same (i tested 3 sbs 2011 installations now). The weird thing however is i use the same setup for installing the mapi runtime on a SBS 2008 server and there we don't see this problem, could this be a problem with the mapi runtime being somehow incompatible with sbs2011 / exchange 2010 ?

EDIT2:
we were wrong in our assumption that the STORE_HTML_OK flag was the cause of the program failing, after some more testing it seems this flags is only set when using the mapi dll from outlook, it's never set in our test when looking with MFC_MAPI at the PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK on the server when using the mapi runtime not even on SBS 2008.

However the problem with the software is related to the PR_BODY_HTML flag, on exchange 2007 (SBS 2008) servers using the mapi runtime we can change this property on exchange 2010 servers (SBS 2011) we can not and get an error when opening the PR_BODY_HTML propert using openproperty that says "the client operation has failed" this seems to be our main problem and the problem of the software we have.

so it's not related to the PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK, maybe i should ask a new question about it, since the problem is not the same as we initally thought?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a server setting. That bit is exposed by the store provider, which runs locally.
What version of MAPI did you install on the machine where your code runs? Is it an older version of Outlook?

Comment: Actually there is no outlook installed, we installed the messaging api and collaboration dataobjects 1.2.1 (mapi runtime) availible from here : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=1004 it is the same installation we install on SBS2008 servers on the server itselve.

Comment: Can you hit the same server from a machine where Outlook is installed (in the online mode) and check that flag with OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI?

Comment: yes i did that and when i check the flag from a client pc with outlook 2007 installed STORE_HTML_OK is set in the PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK, however running the software from a client pc is not an option, we would like it to run from the server (service). Also to my understanding when one uses outlook, the outlook (2007 in this case) mapi32.dll is being used. What i find weird though is that that we use the same mapi runtime on sbs2008 servers and those (when viewed from the server) also show the STORE_HTML_OK flag. So all works except on a SBS 2011 server with exchange 2010 and the mapi runtime

Comment: Hey Dmitry, we were wrong in our assumption that the STORE_HTML_OK flag was the cause of the program failing, after some more testing it seems this flags is only set when using the mapi dll from outlook, it's never set on the server when using the mapi runtime not even on SBS 2008. However the problem with the software is related to the PR_BODY_HTML flag, on exchange 2007 servers using the mapi runtime we can change this property on exchange 2010 servers from sbs2011 we can not and get an error when opening the PR_BODY_HTML propert using openproperty that says "the client operation has failed"